# Background Timer every second, is this the right way?

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

I want to runt a Timer every second. But i don´t want to run it on the UI thread, as to prevent Freezing.

So, i am using another timer than the inbuilt Timer that the Designer offer.
And i am not quite sure if this is the correct approach.

```
  threadtimer = new System.Threading.Timer(timer, null, 1000, Timeout.Infinite);
        private void timer(object obj)
        {
            dowork.....

            threadtimer.Change(1000, Timeout.Infinite);
        }
```

It just seems wrong, i first create the thread, and tells it to run after 1000, for an infinite time.
And still i have to retell it to do that forever.
Why do i even have the second argument if it doesn´t hold?

Comment: how long your `dowork.....` will execute?

Comment: So, the other argument just tells how long it will allow the Thread to live?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/815104/how-to-block-a-timer-while-processing-the-elapsed-event?rq=1

Comment: Nope, If you can tell how long your `dowork` runs I can tell the better way to do.

Comment: @Sriram Sakthivel Oh, well dowork takes probably some ms at best, it just get´s some ints, and updates the GUI.

Comment: Okay, if your method takes more than 1000ms then the way you're doing is correct. else go for `new Timer(timer, null, 1000, 1000);` Your method should be re-entrant in that case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't *have* to do it that way. The third argument (dueTime = 1000) is the delay before the timer is initially called, the fourth (period = infinity) controls the periodic nature, how often subsequent callbacks are done, *not* the time for which to generate callbacks.

The way you have it, there will be a one-second delay between the *end* of the current timer and the time the next one is fired.

If you want it happening every second, you can simply provide 1000 for both those arguments and not worry about having to restart the timer from within the callback.

That *may* end up having multiple callbacks happening if they take longer than a second but, assuming the callback is fast enough, that won't be an issue.

Basically, the first callback will be `arg3` milliseconds after you create the timer then every `arg4` milliseconds after that. More details [here for the constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1cy0c7zw.aspx) and [here for the `Change` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz1c7148.aspx).

Comment: Ah, now that make sense, i thought it was weird that i had to redo the process forever just to keep it alive. Thought i had tested writing the time on both arguments though, but seems i hadn´t. Thanks

Comment: I was sure that passing Timeout.Infinite to the fourth parameter suspend the timer after the first call

Comment: Is it possible to tell it to quit/abort the thread from running, if something happens (like IF(blabla) quit thread)?

Comment: @Steve, infinity for the third argument means create the timer but don't start it.

Comment: Fourth argument, sorry

Comment: @Steve, you're right on the fourth argument. Infinity there means the next callback after the first will occur sometime after the heat death of the universe :-)

Comment: So, if i want to run a thread with a 1 second timer, and Only after it´s finished, the way i used, is the correct? as the callback never occurs and you manually do it?

Comment: @Steve, yes (assuming I've understood your question). Use 1000/inf when creating the timer initially and 1000/inf when changing it at the end of the callback. If your callback takes seven seconds, it will fire at times t = 0, 8, 16 and so on - the next callback will be one second after the end of the previous.

Comment: Ah ok, I was misunderstanding your answer's second paragraph

Comment: @paxdiablo Great, exactly, if i wanted it to run after 1 second, after the process is finished, Nicely many thanks